# Go routines sharing the same net.Conn connection hang on read after one routine exits

Tags: go

I am working on implementing a set of client and server RPC applications. The connections talk to each using JSON over TCP. When I make a single call from my client, I'm able to complete the request and response cycle without issue. However, if I have several go routines sharing a single net.Conn object, when the first go routine exits, the rest of the goroutines hang on reading from the connection (the server still writes back a response if it was in the middle of an RPC call as far as I can tell.) They never reach their waitgroup done calls and the entire process hangs.

main.go, calling the go routines

```
rpcClient := connectAndCreateRpcClient() // has net.Conn from net.Dial

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    for adders := 0; adders < 10; adders++ {
        go func() {

            sum := 0
            for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
                sum += rpcClient.Add(1, 2)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

from the client code, calling the rpc

```
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // .. marshal into jr, append new line as break


    jr = append(jr, byte('\n'))
    _, err = jrc.conn.Write(jr)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    cr := bufio.NewReader(jrc.conn)

    buff, err := cr.ReadBytes(byte('\n'))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // .. unmarshall and return the result
```

from the server, receiving and responding to the client request

```
cr := bufio.NewReader(jrst.conn)

    for {
        rj, err := cr.ReadBytes(byte('\n'))

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        }

        // ... un marshall the request ...

            res, err := cbs.Unary(req.Method, req.Params) 
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unary return: %s\n", err.Error())
            }
                        // .. marshall up the response

                    br = append(br, byte('\n'))

                    _, err = jrst.conn.Write(br)
                   if err != nil {
                    return err

                   }
```

I left most of the data wrangling code out because the important thing seems to be that when one of the 10 go routines in main completes its 100 calls, the other 9 go routines are hanging on `buff, err := cr.ReadBytes(byte('\n'))`

Why does a go routine finishing seem to stop the others from reading? Is there a better way to implement my reads and writes to keep the connection alive properly?

Comment: It is unlikely that you have connection related problems. You seem to have protocol related problems. How do you know each goroutine receives the result for the query it sent? Network IO is buffered, it is likely that all goroutines write their requests in some random order, and one of the buffered readers is reading all the responses.

Comment: Interesting point; an empty buffer would certainly cause the reads to hang. I knew that each go routine wasn’t necessarily getting the result for its query (a larger problem but ok in this case) but I’m surprised that the entire buffer would get cleared when each read should be one line, since I’m delineating each request/response with a newline character.

Comment: A buffered reader will read more than you expect. If you are planning to use one connection, then have one goroutine to read and dispatch others.